# In python how take take inputs ( L , R ) at a time in a singe line like this - L=10 T=20

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

In python how to take inputs ( L, R ) simultaneously in a single line like this - `L=10 T=20`
Example output:
`case #1`: 10 20 ( Here L = 10 and R = 20 )

How to give input like this in a single line? is it possible with arrays?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily by using the `split()`:

```py
l, t = input("Enter input").split()
print(l, t)
```

`>>> 10 20`

The `split()` returns a list that can be unpacked easily. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).